# How can I require different modules in Javascript based on my YML build file?

Tags: javascript, build, electron

I'm currently working on a web game that will also be available as a desktop application via [electron](http://electron.atom.io/). I'd like to simply not `require('electron')` if I am building the web version of the game.

My .yml file that I use with [build](https://atom.io/packages/build) is as follows:

```
cmd: browserify {PROJECT_PATH}/js/main.js > {PROJECT_PATH}/js/bundle.js && {PROJECT_PATH}/index.html
name: 'web'
targets:
  electron:
    cmd: browserify {PROJECT_PATH}/js/main.js > {PROJECT_PATH}/js/bundle.js && electron {PROJECT_PATH}
```

If my build command was something like `node main.js true`, I could just reference the boolean argument and then use it in the Javascript to either `require('electron')` or not. However, I'm not sure how this can be done given my current situation.

In other words, I'd like to pass a boolean argument via my .yml build file, and use said boolean somewhat like this:

```
if (passedBoolean) {
  const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
}
```

How would I do this? If it's not possible, what would be another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways that you could approach solving this problem. The first is to query the platform about its capabilities. For example, Electron sets the variable:

```
process.versions.electron
```

This won't be set if you're running in the browser, so you can check for its existence (and you'll know you're running in Electron). Here's the documentation: [Electron: Process](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/process/).

Testing for a nested property can be a bit gross, so a slightly simpler way is to wrap your attempt to access the value in a try/catch:

```
try {
    process.versions.electron; 
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Not electron', err);
}
```

You could even wrap it into a nice function:

```
function isPlatformElectron() {
    'use strict';
    try {
        process.versions.electron;
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isPlatformElectron()) {
    // Do Electron-specific stuff here
}
```

You could alternatively do something like this with your original code (slightly modified):

```
let app, BrowserWindow;
try {
    ({app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron'));
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Not electron');
}

if (app && BrowserWindow) {
   console.log('is electron');
}
```

I find this version harder to read and prefer the function approach I suggested above, but I thought it might be useful to show the example using destructuring like your original (although you can't use const in this case).